# API to access restaurant menu data

Tags: api, service

Can anybody tell me if there is any API/Web Service to access restaurant menus? which can give list of various appetizers, beverages, etc available at the restaurant?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I did a little more search and found this - http://www.openmenu.com/. Openmenu is trying to standardize menu structure and format and they have already 30k menus. Their API is coming soon.

Just because some restaurant does not have a website, does not mean that they can't send a simple text file of their menu to some service like Openmenu.

Comment: https://openmenu.com/api/

It is 0.20/credit, and one call is a credit.

Comment: @technazi I'm not sure how much this has changed in the last few years, but it's currently $0.02 per call. Looks like you might have made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how recent this startup is, but it claims to have restaurants info: http://dev.locu.com/

I have yet to try their API.

Also there's a list here: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/06/05/35-restaurant-apis-unofficial-open-table-food-genius-and-menu-mania/

Comment: Locu seems to be offline, did anyone try this recently?

Comment: GoDaddy shut off developer signup after acquisition in January 2017. They may have also shut off access to existing developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can access all the restaurants menu, in India by [Zomato open api](https://developers.zomato.com/api).but you can make 1000 hits per day only