# Google Map google place type

Tags: android, google-maps

I implemented Google Maps in my application.
I used the nearby places for example (nearby restaurant).
Is it possible to get their menus in the restaurant?
Do the Google APIs provide that information?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=google+restaurant+menu

Comment: do they have api for this?

Comment: this should address your q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454795/restaurant-menu-search-api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177430/api-to-access-restaurant-menu-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not yet possible for various reasons.

First of all, menus in restaurants change over time. Some even offer different cuisine depending on the season, days of the week or availability of the food. In addition to that, not all restaurants have a website or other source from where Google can fetch their menu and display it to users.

To your benefit, what Google maps does is provide a link to the website of the restaurant, if this is available. There you would normally have a menu, and some photos of the kind of environment you will find when choosing to eat at this restaurant. Maps also offers the possibility to at least tell you what kind of restaurant it is (what cuisine it offers), if the restaurant gives out this information.

It would be nice to have this feature available in the future. It will definitely revamp the choice of restaurants being made, and not leaving it to be simply based on other users' reviews.

Comment: Very well said. Yes it would be nice to have that feature. My employer ask mo to do that, if its not i will do it manually. OMG.

Comment: This answer same to car_services right? like what services does car shop offered. something like that

Comment: actually its not the menu of a restaurant i wanted. but the car services of a certain carshop/car repair. I thought its just the same. i just use restaurant for easier approach

Comment: I guess that becomes more difficult then, as garages are not always licensed and their products may vary.

Comment: yes. i thought so.. So what if I get all of their phone number and call them one by one to ask for what services they offered. Am i being insane or crazy or what? :/

Comment: It is an option :) Or else you could build your own database of garages with the list of services they offer. You could easily use the id returned by Google Places for each unique garage, and build a database which stores the services offered by that garage. When querying for a garage offering the services you need, you would first query the Google Places API to get the list of Garages around you. Then you would use the result of that, to query your database and limit the result only to those garages offering the services you need.

Comment: I will go for that idea. But it will take time. But thank you so much for your time. Hoping for google to solve this for me lol

Comment: Can you please upvote if this answer has helped you? :)

Comment: I should link this to my employer to get his trust that I am not joking about this. LOL